# Making single letters non-italic in Graphics/Text/Style objects

Tags: graphics, style

Suppose that I use `Graphics`, `Text`, and `Style` to type one letter in the subscript of a letter and one in the superscript of the same letter.  In the Writing Assistant in Mathematica 9, I click the [image: button] button to help typeset the string in this command:

```
Graphics[Text[
  Style["\!\(\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(A\), \(B\), \(C\)]\)", 30, 
   FontFamily -> "Arial"]]]
```

The graphical output is the following.

[image: example]

Why do the letters A, B, and C appear italic, even though I did not specify them as such?  I want the letters to all be regular font.  The italicization does not happen if I take out the `Graphics` directive, and just use `Text` and `Style`.  But I have to use `Graphics` because I will ultimately include it in a plot.

Comment: check out [`SingleLetterItalics`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/SingleLetterItalics.html)

Comment: you can change the single letter italics, referenced in the previous comment, like this: `Graphics[Text[Style["...", 30,FontFamily -> "Arial",SingleLetterItalics -> False]]]`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
Graphics[Text[
  Style[Subsuperscript["A", "B", "C"], 30, FontFamily -> "Arial", 
   SingleLetterItalics -> False]]]
```

[image]

or

```
Graphics[Text[
  Style[Subsuperscript[Style["A", Italic], "B", "C"], 30, 
   FontFamily -> "Arial", SingleLetterItalics -> False]]]
```

[image]

Comment: The very subtle difference lurks in from the difference of `SubscriptBox` and `Subscript`! With `Subscript` the text is upright in `Graphics` by default (v11).