# "Graphics" will cause text tilted

Tags: graphics, text

I feel `Graphics` will make text tilted. As

```mathematica
Text[Style["\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(R\), \(2\)]\)", 
  FontFamily -> "Times New Roman"]]
```

will output:

[image]

But

```mathematica
Graphics[
 Text[Style["\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(R\), \(2\)]\)", 
   FontFamily -> "Times New Roman"]]]
```

will output:
[image]

Obviously, the text in Graphics become tilted. What's the reason and how to fix it?

Comment: This is how graphics seems to work with text. see [making-single-letters-non-italic-in-graphics-text-style-objects](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/46242/making-single-letters-non-italic-in-graphics-text-style-objects)  I can give you a workaround using  rasterize if you want. But I do not know why Graphics changes it to italic. It seems build in.

Comment: @Nasser  Thanks a lot. I will close this post a few minutes later.

Comment: I think you should wait few days. May be someone will come with an idea or some other solution? I never noticed this myself before.

Comment: @Nasser Try this `Graphics[
 Text[Style["\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(Ca\), \(\(2\)\(+\)\)]\)", 
   FontFamily -> "Times New Roman"]]]`, you will find this is not tilted, and it is just sometimes tilted for some characters.

Comment: To tell you the truth, I myself use MaTeX/Latex for all my labeling and texts of plots and graphics in Mathematica for school. It looks better and do not have to deal with such issues.

Comment: @Nasser But, the characters of that file converted to PDF can't be selected and copied.

Comment: I never had reason to copy labels and math equations as text from PDF file myself. But if this is something you need to do, I can understand that MaTeX/Latex solution will not work, as its output is an image. I do not know of a workaround this.

Comment: @Nasser I don't need to copy either. I just feel that the characters that can be copied will be better than not.  The feature of not be copied may be related to the **Ghostscript**, I guess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is due to the fact that you write R squared. Mma automatically makes it Italic. There is a simple workaround: write R in quotes: "R", but the power outside of the quotes, like in the image below:

[image]

That is:

```
Graphics[Text[Style[("R")^2, FontFamily -> "Times"]]]
```

Another way is to use the option `SingleLetterItalics -> False`:

```
Graphics[Text[Style[R^2, FontFamily -> "Times", SingleLetterItalics -> False]]]
```

with the following effect:

[image]

Have fun!

Comment: So **Mathematica** only will tilt the **R^2**, not to most characters. Am I right?

Comment: @Y. zeng You are right. Es makes Italics any letter with super- and/or subscript.

Comment: What is **Es**?

Comment: Excuse me, it should be "It" instead of "Es". Its a miswriting.

Comment: Okay. Thanks a lot.